# android locationlistener carries on calling onlocationChanged after unregistering listener

Tags: android, gps, location

I've an app that gets the user's location. I've registered the locationManager and listener in oncreate(). I've requested and removed updates in onResume() and onPause() respectively. The app finds the location and calls the getTime() on the loc object of onLocationChanged, this is to get an external time and then later compare to system time. This time is set in an applicationObject so that it's available app-wide. Everything works fine and i toast the time to the user from the applicationObject time setter method.

What i'm finding is that when i have found the time by getting a fix on the user's location, and i move to the next activity, the app continues to get the time for another 20 secs and sometimes more.

How can this be when i have unregistered the locaction listener in the first activity's onPause() method?

```
    @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
            super.onPause();
        }


    @Override
        protected void onResume() {

             mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
            super.onResume();
        }

         private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {



                    Log.e(TAG, "external time = " + loc.getTime());
                    DateTime dt = new DateTime(loc.getTime());
                    DateTimeFormatter df3 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.SSS");
                    String formattedNowTime3 = df3.print(dt);
                    Log.e(TAG, "formatted ext time = " + formattedNowTime3);
                    nfcscannerapplication.setExternalTime(dt);

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                }//end of MyLocationListener


@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.entryscreen);

        mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
```

.

Comment: Are you sure that you unresgister in `onPause()` and not in `onStop()`? The later is called only a few seconds after you exit the activity. If you are unregistering in `onPause()`, write a `Log` message in there, so you can compare the time when it´s executed with the `onLocationChange()` updates stopping, for debugging porposes.

Comment: @Luis Hi yes the onPause() method of the first activity is getting called after the user enters the second activity. How is this possible. I thought android would call onpause() first before another activity comes to the forefront? Where should i remove the updates and listener then?

Comment: If you only want a single `onLocationChange()`, you can use `requestSingleUpdate()` and your problem is gone.

Comment: @Luis Brilliant, exactly what i want. I'd would like to know why android continues to request updates after i have removed them in onStop(). If you would like to create an answer i'll accept for your last comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onPause()` may be called only after the new activity has started.

If you only want a single `onLocationChange()`, you can use `requestSingleUpdate()` and your problem is gone.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Set mlocListener to null just after removeUpdates();

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It still continues to get the location maybe another 10 updates after removing updates and setting listener to null. Why do you think this is?

Comment: put a log on onPause and see if it  really calls onPasuse().Maybe it never calls it.And also what luis say about requestSingleUpdate() seems legit.